# UIScrollView. There is strange behavior of Paging if contentOffset is too large

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, scroll-paging

Paging of `UIScrollView` by Apple has delay at `contentOffset.y` about 10000000, and don't come back in the origin state if we will do partial swipe at `contentOffset.y` about 18900000. You can check it creating simple app with the code of `mainView`:

```
@implementation MainView

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        self.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
        UIScrollView *scroll = [UIScrollView new];
        scroll.frame = self.frame;
        scroll.contentSize = (CGSize){ CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), 20000000.0 };
        scroll.contentOffset = (CGPoint){ 0.0, 18900000.0 };
        scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
        scroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

        for (float i = 0; i < 20000000.0; i += 500.0)
        {
            UIView *line = [UIView new];
            line.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            line.frame = (CGRect){ 0, i, self.frame.size.width, 30.0 };
            [scroll addSubview:line];
        }

        [self addSubview:scroll];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Why it's happen? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed after reporting to the Apple Bug Reporter. In new versions of XCode you'll see that all is correct.